# Binomial sum identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Everyone knows that $\sum{n \choose 2k}=\sum{n \choose 2k+1}$

My question is follwing

What is the clear form of $\sum_{k=0} (-1)^k{n \choose 2k}$ and $\sum_{k=0} (-1)^k{n \choose 2k+1}$

For example, my exercise is

"calculate a+b where a=$\sum_{k=0}^{25} (-1)^k{50 \choose 2k}$ & b=$\sum_{k=0}^{24} (-1)^k{50 \choose 2k+1}$"

I found that it is relative to number 4.

If n has a form 4k+2 then a=0 and b=$(-1)^k2^{2k+1}$ or If n has a form 4k then b=0 and a=$(-1)^k2^{2k}$

But it's just my hypothesis.(I just wrote it when n=1,2,3,...,10 and found a rule)

Comment: I want to know simple calculation of a and b in my example by not using any recurrence formula as well as clear forms.

Comment: You can separate k when it is an odd and even numbers, and use a change of variable. Thus, you can use $\sum{n \choose 2k}=\sum{n \choose 2k+1}$ twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with
$$
(1 + i)^{n} 
=
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} i^{k}
=
\sum_{h} \binom{n}{2 h} (-1)^{h} 
+
i \sum_{h} \binom{n}{2 h + 1} (-1)^{h},
$$
and then note that
\begin{align}
(1 + i)^{n} 
&= 
\sqrt{2}^{n} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{n}
\\&=
\sqrt{2}^{n} \cdot \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \right)^{n}
\\&=
\sqrt{2}^{n} \cdot \left( \cos\left(n \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i \sin\left(n \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \right).
\end{align}

---

Note that this extends the argument for the case you mentioned
$$
0 = (1 + (-1))^{n} 
=
\sum_{h} \binom{n}{2 h} 
-
\sum_{h} \binom{n}{2 h + 1}.
$$

---

The download of [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) is to be recommended.